# Fitting image in a grid

Tags: html, css, image

I'm a rookie "programing" and asking for help here in stackoverflow.

I'm having a little problem trying to fit an image inside my grid.

For example, when I have an image with a specific size it works but when I have an image a bit larger or in a different format (16:9 instead of 9:16) it show the image not in the full size but not cut it to fit the grid .

[What I Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlXbB.jpg)

[What I Get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UObur.jpg)

I use the same HTML code and CSS for both grids the only thing that changes it's the image. *I'm using Bootstrap with some CSS.*

**The CSS**

```css
.grid {
position: relative;
clear: both;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1000px;

list-style: none;
text-align: center;
}

.grid figure {
position: relative; 
overflow: hidden;
margin: 10px 0;
height: auto;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
}

.grid figure img {
position: relative;
display: block;
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="gallery-grids">

            <div class="col-md-4 gallery-grid">
                <div class="grid">
                    <figure  class="effect-roxy">
                        <a  class="example-image-link" href="/images/fotos/gal1.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="In lacinia pharetra ipsum vel dapibus. Ut vitae tristique nisi, mattis pellentesque elit. Proin mollis sed nisi ac sodales.">
                            <img src="/images/fotos/gal1.jpg" alt="" />
                            <figcaption>
                                <h3>Maecenas <span>lacus</span></h3>
                                <p> Aenean fermentum nisl ac imperdiet commodo</p>
                            </figcaption>   
                        </a>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap but with some changes so everything may not work

Comment: It appears you are using bootstrap? Also, could you include a little bit more HTML. It would help to see what you are doing. Thanks!

Comment: Updated the code with the full div

Comment: The images are missing in the snippet.

Comment: i don't know how to add the image to the snipet, the is the link https://imgur.com/a/5HyLdtv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create a trim **class** in **CSS** like this

```
div.trim {
max-height:292.2px;
max-width: 350px;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

then add a new  out of the image div to lock it

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="gallery-grids">
            
            <div class="col-md-4 gallery-grid">
                <div class="grid">
                        <figure  class="effect-roxy">
                            <div class="trim" >
                            <a class="example-image-link" href="{$product.image}" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="">
                                <img src="{$product.image}" alt="" />
                                <!--<figcaption>
                                    <h3>Maecenas <span>lacus</span></h3>
                                    <p> Aenean fermentum nisl ac imperdiet commodo</p>-->
                                </figcaption>
                            </a></div>
                        </figure>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have 2 options, one is to add images as backround and use cover, or if images comes from img tag then use

```
img {
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}
```

Note, this does not work in old ie version

Comment: it did not work, still have the image with the same size

Comment: try setting max height maybe, sharing something like jsfiddle could help a lot

Comment: it does not have all information so is very bad, but atleast you have the code https://jsfiddle.net/kc82hr7j/